# "cross this line" versus "cross the line"

Tags: articles

This is written on a railroad platform:

[image: Image of the edge of a railway platform. Part of the track can be seen at the top. In the centre in yellow cyrillic writing "СТОИ! ЗАХОДЗІЧЬ ЗА ЛІНІЮ НЕБЯСПЕЧНА!" and below that the English phrase "DANGER! DO NOT CROSS THIS LINE!" beside the text, on either side are yellow footprints with crosses through. Below the message is a yellow, studded line.]

Is the English text OK?

Or "cross the line" is better?

Or both are equally correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instructions in your image are correct because they state specifically which line not to cross.

**(Do not) "Cross *the* line"** is used idiomatically to warn someone not to exceed a threshold (the line) in a particular action or behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This refers to something in close proximity to the statement. If you *say* "this", then the "this X" is close to you. If "this" is written, then the "this thing" will be close to the writing. In this case, there is a line right next to the writing, so it's pretty clear what is being said.

"The" on the other hand means "specific", "the dog" means only one very certain dog. Because there's only one very certain line here, "the" could be used as well. The difference is semantics, literally, so either one could be used.

Answer (score 0):

I think "this line" is better, perhaps because it is more emphatic.